# Why is it possible to pass a callback of type `int Function()` as a `void Function()` (e.g. for Flutter setState)?

Tags: flutter, dart

The Flutter `setState` function has signature:

```
void setState (VoidCallback fn) // VoidCallback equivalent to `void Function()`
```

The documentation states that it takes callbacks that have no arguments and no return value.

I notice that it is perfectly legal to pass `setState` a function like this (in the case of the default Flutter create example app):

```dart
void _incrementCounter() {
  setState(() => _counter++);
}
```

However `() => _counter++` defines a function that returns a value: `int Function()`.

So I created my own test:

```
void setState(void Function() fn) {
  fn();
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {

  //Ordinary int function
  int a() {
    print('go tiger!');
    return 5;
  }

  setState(a);
}
```

And this works just fine! Am I missing something? Why is it possible to pass `setState` a function callback with a return value?

p.s: If I add a parameter to a - so `int a(int b)` then it complains correctly -

```
The argument type 'int Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'. argument_type_not_assignable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dart treats a function that returns a non-`void` type as a subtype of a function that returns a `void` type.  That is, a function that returns something is *substitutable* for a function that returns nothing; you just discard the return value.

Additionally, a `void` type in Dart really means that the value cannot be *used*.  For example, this is legal:

```dart
void x = 5;
```

Additional reading: [The curious case of void in Dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-curious-case-of-void-in-dart-f0535705e529)

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated