# Function is not a valid override of parent methods

Tags: dart, inheritance, compiler-errors, implements

How to implement D class which implements A, B & C classes.

I am understanding multiple inheritance in dart. In the below program the D class implements A, B, & C classes but its generating compile time error that `'D.foo' ('String Function()') isn't a valid override of 'A.foo' ('int Function()').`

I have went through some of the previous post in SO but still unsure how to fix this issue:

- [void Function(int) isn't a valid override of void Function(dynamic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966135/void-functionint-isnt-a-valid-override-of-void-functiondynamic)
- [void Function(Subype) isn't a valid override of void Function(ParentType)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620054/void-functionsubype-isnt-a-valid-override-of-void-functionparenttype)

### Source

```
class $ {
  void bar() {
    print("\$ bar");
  }
}

class A extends $ {
  int foo() {
    print("A's foo");
    return 0;
  }
}

class B extends $ {
  String foo() {
    print("B's foo");
    return "Bla";
  }
}

class C extends $ {
  void foo() {
    print("C's foo");
  }
}

class D implements A, B, C {
  @override
  void bar() {}

  String foo() { // Error @ this line seems its not a valid override
    return "Object()";
  }
}
```

Comment: You fix it by not doing it.  What are you trying to accomplish where a child class changes the type like that?  That violates the rules for class extension because a member of the child class should be able to act like a member of the parent class.

Comment: You can't implement all three of these, they contradict each other on what a `foo` is expected to return. Since `D` is an `A` it must return an `int` from `foo`, but since `D` is also a `B` it must return a `String` from `foo`. You can't meet both requirements.

Comment: @Randal you are correct `member of the child class should be able to act like a member of the parent class`. I'm understanding and testing the possibility that exists in inheritance. Suppose we have an abstract parent `class A` with method `void foo()`, its inherited by `class B` and overrides `foo` as `int foo()`, we can instanciate `B` and use it. Why dart allows this the return type aren't same?

Comment: @mmcdon20 `VS Code` editor gives warning as [inconsistent  inheritance](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?#inconsistent_inheritance). Is there's a way that *satisfies all the inherited signatures*?

Comment: The implemention `String foo() {return "Object()";}` in `D` does not satisfy all of the signatures of `foo` in all of the classes you are implementing. Like I mentioned, class `A` expects a return type of `int` in its signature.

Comment: Also no you can't satisfy all of the signatures because there is no type that is a subtype of both `String` and `int`. Also you cannot create such a type either since you are not allowed to `extend`/`implement` `String` or `int`.

Comment: Actually you can satisfy all signatures, but only if you use `Never` as the return type since `Never` is a subtype of everything (also known as a bottom type). `Never foo() { throw('example'); }` would satisfy all signaures.

Comment: @Udesh "Why dart allows this the return type aren't same?" See [Why is it possible to pass a callback of type `int Function()` as a `void Function()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308270/)