# Handling errors in void Dart function marked async

Tags: dart, error-handling, async-await, try-catch, void

I am designing an API and would like to handle a situation when a user marks a `void` function `async` by mistake.

The simplified code is listed below:

```
void test(void Function() run) {
  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      print(i);
      run();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  } finally {
    print('in finally block.');
  }
}

void errorThrower(String message) {
  print('in errorThrower ');
  throw message;
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  test(() async{  // <-------- marked async by API user's mistake
    print('in run ...');
    errorThrower('error thrown in test');
  });
}
```

If the function is **not** marked `async` the program output is as expected and the error is
thrown, caught, handled, and the `finally` block is executed:

```bash
$ dart main.dart
0
in run ...
in errorThrower 
error thrown in test
in finally block.
```

However, if the function is marked `async` the console output is:

```bash
$ dart main.dart 
0
in run ...
in errorThrower 
1
in run ...
in errorThrower 
2
in run ...
in errorThrower 
in finally block.
Unhandled exception:
error thrown in test
#0      errorThrower (file:///home/dan/WORK/DartProjects/benchmark_runner/bin/throws_test.dart:16:3)
#1      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///main.dart:22:5)
#2      test (file:///main.dart:5:10)
#3      main (file:///main.dart:20:3)
#4      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:294:33)
#5      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
```

What is going on? I tried a debugger, the program steps into `run()` then `errorThrower` and then the loop continues.
It looks like an unawaited future error but I don't know how to catch and handle it since a `void` function cannot be awaited.

Is there any way I can catch  and handle the error without changing the signature o f `run()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is going on?

Functions marked with `async` are automatically transformed so that return values and thrown objects are wrapped in `Future`s.  Failed `Future`s must be handled by registering a callback with [`Future.catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/catchError.html), by using using `await` on the `Future` within a `try` block (which is syntactic sugar for registering a `Future.catchError` callback), or by setting up a [`Zone`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Zone-class.html) error handler (which I'll consider to be outside the scope of this answer).  Conceptually you can consider a failed `Future` as throwing an exception from the Dart event loop, after your *synchronous* `test` function has already left its `try`-`catch` block.

> Is there any way I can catch and handle the error without changing the signature of `run()`?

[A `T Function()` is a subtype of (is substitutable for) `void Function()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308270/).  Therefore at compile-time you cannot prevent a `Future<void> Function()` from being passed where a `void Function()` is expected.  This is also why things like `Iterable.forEach` can't prevent asynchronous callbacks ([even though it's almost always a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719805/)) and [would need support from the linter](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/891).

You could add a runtime check:

```dart
void test(void Function() run) {
  if (run is Future<void> Function()) {
    throw ArgumentError("test: Cannot be used with asynchronous callbacks."); 
  }
  ...
}
```

Or if you just want to swallow the error:

```dart
void test(void Function() run) {
  ...
  if (run is Future<void> Function()) {
    run().catchError((e) => print(e));
  } else {
    run();
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that if you want `test` to wait for `run` to complete (successfully or not), then `test` itself would need to be asynchronous and would need to return a `Future`.  At that point, you might as well always assume that `run` might be asynchronous and unconditionally `await` it:

```dart
Future<void> test(FutureOr<void> Function() run) async {
  try {
    ...
    await run();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See, i can explain about the difference in your expected result and actual result.

Look when you mark a function as `async`, it means that the function returns a special type of object called a `Future`. A `Future` represents a potentially `asynchronous` operation that may or may not be completed. When you call an `async` function, it returns immediately, and the work inside the function happens in the `background`. This is what enables Dart to perform `asynchronous programming`.

And in your `test` function, you are taking another function called run as an argument. When you mark run as `async`, it means it's returning a `Future<void>`, and when you call it `without await`, the function execution is not paused to wait for the run function to complete. Instead, it `continues` with the loop immediately.

This is why you see the loop running without waiting for the run function to finish. It's running concurrently, and the `exceptions` it throws aren't caught in the `try/catch` block because the `try/catch` block is already completed before the run function finishes.

And the Code below will lead to your expected answer:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> test(Future<void> Function() run) async {
  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      print(i);
      await run(); // Await the execution of the async function.
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  } finally {
    print('In finally block.');
  }
}

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  await test(() async {
    throw 'In void function erroneously marked async';
  });
}
```

Now, think how it's give expected result! reply if you don't get.

Comment: Thank you, your reply is helpful but does not answer the question. In my example, I can't change the signature of `run()`. And the statement "When you call an `async` function, it returns immediately, and the work inside the function happens in the background." is not entirely accurate since code in an `async` function is executed synchronously until the first awaited future is encountered.

Comment: I have amended the callback `run()` to highlight that code in an `async` function is executed synchronously until the first `await` statement is encountered.